# ggplot2() fix x-axis for melt variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting multiple vectors in one graph with ggplot2.
I have the following dataframe

| Array | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arr1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.4 | 0.7 |
| Arr2 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| Arr3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.2 |
| Arr4 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.9 |
| B | a | a | a | b | b | b | a | a | a | b |
| C | b | b | b | a | a | b | b | a | b | a |

So I melt the data to plot all vectors with horizontal stack bar, which is as follows:

```
df2<-df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Array") %>%
  mutate(variable = str_extract(variable, "[0-9]+")) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    value == "a" ~ 1,
    value == "b" ~ 2, 
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(value)
  )) %>%
  mutate(variable = as.numeric(variable))
  
df2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Array, y = variable, group = Array, fill = value)) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

But the x-axis is not proper, the image shows that same number of `a` and `b` in vector `B` has different sizes, also last single element has bigger size than first three. The problem in x-axis is easier to detect with vector `B and C` then `Arr`.

When you look at df2 `variable` only has 1 to 10, I cannot figure out how there are more than 50 points on x - axis.

[image: Graph]

Comment: I'm having trouble duplicating this.  Please add the results of dput(df) to your question.  Also please show what packages you are using `library(tidyverse)` `library(reshape2)` ?

Comment: Yes ```library(tidyverse) and library(reshape2)``` are used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because each bar is stacking the y (variables). For each Array category, the bar is stacking from 1 to 10, the total is 1+2+...+10 = 55, that's why you see the x-axis is over 50. That's also the reason that B and C have different sizes for a and b. The first blue blocks for B and C are: (a, a, a) = (1+2+3) = 6 and (b, b, b) = (1+2+3) = 6, they have the same size.  The second blue blocks for B and C are: (b, b ,b) = (4+5+6) = 15 and (a, a) = (4+5) =9, they have different sizes.

If you want the x-axis to have range between 1-10 and the B and C have same sizes for a and b. Set your `y (variable)` to be a vector of 1.

```
df2<-df %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Array") %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(
    value == "a" ~ 1,
    value == "b" ~ 2, 
    TRUE ~ as.numeric(value)
  )) %>%
  mutate(variable = 1) # change to 1
```

Update legend: you can use `scale_fill_continuous()` to customize the legend text. Using the code below, you will get legend in the picture.[image]

```
df2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Array, y = variable, group = Array, fill = value)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(breaks = c(0.1, 1, 2), labels = c("0.1", "1 (=a)", "2 (=b)"))+
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks @Xiang, could you help me to add legend of ```B``` and ```C``` as ```a``` and ```b``` rather then a number? Its fine if you split ```B``` and ```C```  into one graph and all ```Arr``` into other with 2 seperate legends.

Comment: I have updated the answer to address the legend question.

Comment: Is it possible to get distinct color instead of blue gradient for each break to properly differentiate